# How do I reset the count of auto-numbered headings for each container element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I am using the following code to create an ordered list out of H4 elements:

```
$(function() {
    $(".numbered > h4").each(function(i, n) {
      $(this).prepend("<span>" + (i+1) + ". " + "</span> ");
    });
  });
```

This works great but I want the count to reset for every container (.numbered). For example, I have a container div with four h4's and this code will prepend that number but does not reset for each div. So the second div on the page would start its count at 5 instead of 1. 1 is the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `i` to start over for each `numbered`, break up the lookup so you perform two each.

```
$(function() {
    $(".numbered").each(function(_, numbered){
        $('> h4', numbered).each(function(i) {
            $(this).prepend("<span>" + (i+1) + ". " + "</span> ");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop through each `.numbered` element, and then within that loop, loop through each `h4` element. Similar to this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".numbered").each(function(i, n) {
        $(n).children("h4").each(function(i,n) {
            $(this).prepend("<span>" + (i+1) + ". " + "</span> ");
        });
    });
  });
```

Comment: I marked another solution as correct but yours worked as well. Thank you!